# Mobilenet to detect multiple classes in an image with coordinates

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I have followed the tutorial 
(https://towardsdatascience.com/keras-transfer-learning-for-beginners-6c9b8b7143e) 
to classify objects. Right now I have a model which can classify whether the given image is a cat, dog or horse.

Now I need to modify the code in such a way that if an image containing a cat, dog and horse is given, it should detect all the three with the bounding boxes and probabilities

1. Any modules in keras or tensorflow to be added to serve this purpose
2. ***Is it the last layer to be changed?*** If so, what to be changed there

Currently the model looks like this (with last layer having the number of classes)

```
base_model=MobileNet(weights='imagenet',include_top=False)

x=base_model.output
x=GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x=Dense(1024,activation='relu')(x) 
x=Dense(1024,activation='relu')(x) 
x=Dense(512,activation='relu')(x) 
preds=Dense(3,activation='softmax')(x) ***LAST LAYER***
```

And the prediction goes like this

```
img = image.load_img("nethorse.jpeg", target_size = (224,224))
test_image = image.img_to_array(img)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
test_image  =preprocess_input(test_image)
print(test_image)
```

which says that it is horse with 0.99 probability

So, the code is to be modified in such a way that the existing model can not only say what object is present in an image but also give its coordinates(i.e detect multiple objects in an image with bounding boxes)

Comment: Don't make an object detection model yourself, just use any state of the art model, like Faster R-CNN, YOLO, SSD, etc.

Comment: Thanks Matias. I've used YOLO and it's great. And I've also read the mobilenet paper(it shows object detection figures) and what I want to know is can we get the object detection model by adding/changing the last few layers. Because it's all about the numbers getting at the last layers.

Comment: Yes, the paper says they use MobileNets together with Faster R-CNN and SSD, those are your last layers on top of the trunk network which is MobileNets.